# Adding string to href in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, migration, href, crud

A client wants to have **CRUD** functionality for events on their website.

In the migration up() method, I currently have the following for the schema:

```
$table->string('date');
$table->string('location');
```

On the website, I have an RSVP button.

How would I make an additional column for the user to add a ***url*** to their facebook event in the ***href*** inside the button?

TL;DR:

What should I do to get this to insert into the href? :

```
$table->string('url');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already passing an object to the view, do this:

```
<a href="{{ $object->url }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The migration is just setting up your database. You still need to populate it with data.

```
$table->string('url');
```

That is fine for your migration, but if you want the user to be able to enter the URL, you'll have to add a form to the front-end view for the user to provide the URL.

Then on the backend, you'll need a route in your routes file that points to a controller that processes the form submission and inserts or updates the database record with a model object.

You'll also need to add the 'url' field to the $fillable array on whatever model your migration was for:

```
protected $fillable = [..., 'url'];
```

You could check out this tutorial which has a [CRUD example from scratch for Laravel 5.4](https://appdividend.com/2017/05/02/laravel-5-4-crud-example-scratch/)